# Why doesn't my code listen?

Tags: java, dna-sequence

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseCompliment 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      String seqFirst = "0";
      String seqSecond = "0";
      String seqReverseCompliment = "";
      boolean isOrIsNot = true;

      System.out.print("Enter the first sequence: ");
      seqFirst = in.next();
      System.out.print("Enter the second sequence: ");
      seqSecond = in.next();

      for ( int i = 0; i < seqFirst.length(); i++)
      {
         if ( seqFirst.charAt(i) == 'A')
         {
            seqReverseCompliment = "T" + seqReverseCompliment;
         }
         else if ( seqFirst.charAt(i) == 'T')
         {
            seqReverseCompliment = "A" + seqReverseCompliment;
         }
         else if ( seqFirst.charAt(i) == 'C')
         {
            seqReverseCompliment = "G" + seqReverseCompliment;
         }
         else if ( seqFirst.charAt(i) == 'G')
         {
            seqReverseCompliment = "C" + seqReverseCompliment;
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.println("incorrect input");
         }
      }
       for ( int i = 0; i < seqFirst.length(); i++)
       {
          if ( seqSecond.charAt(i) != seqReverseCompliment.charAt(i) )
          {
             isOrIsNot = false;
          }
          else if ( seqSecond.charAt(i) == seqReverseCompliment.charAt(i) )
          {
             isOrIsNot = true;
          }
       }
       if ( isOrIsNot = true )
       {
          System.out.println("These are reverse compliments");
       }
       else if (
       {
          System.out.println("These are not reverse compliments");
       }
   }
}
```

Essentially I need the user to input two DNA sequences, and then the program needs to compare them and determine if the two sequences are reverse compliments of each other. I'm not looking for someone to complete this assignment for me, I'm just at a loss as to why it doesn't work properly.
When I test it it always says that the two are reverse compliments.

[screenshot of assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYx2o.png)

Comment: You have to provide more details. "*doesn't work properly*" is insufficient.

Comment: "When i test it it always says the two are reverse compliments"    As in no matter the input, the program always says the two are reverse compliments

Comment: Your `isOrIsNot` variable reflects just the last comparison. You need to `break` from the loop once the first mismatch is found.

Comment: You need to break the loop on first mismatch and your boolean comparison require `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: I changed it, same problem. i input "AAA" then "GGG" and it recognizes as reverse compliments, which is incorrect

Comment: Avi , that worked. im trying the answer from below because its cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just compare `seqSecond` with `seqReverseCompliment` using `String.equals`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseCompliment 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      String seqFirst = "0";
      String seqSecond = "0";
      String seqReverseCompliment = "";

      System.out.print("Enter the first sequence: ");
      seqFirst = in.next();
      System.out.print("Enter the second sequence: ");
      seqSecond = in.next();

      for ( int i = 0; i < seqFirst.length(); i++)
      {
         if ( seqFirst.charAt(i) == 'A')
         {
            seqReverseCompliment = "T" + seqReverseCompliment;
         }
         else if ( seqFirst.charAt(i) == 'T')
         {
            seqReverseCompliment = "A" + seqReverseCompliment;
         }
         else if ( seqFirst.charAt(i) == 'C')
         {
            seqReverseCompliment = "G" + seqReverseCompliment;
         }
         else if ( seqFirst.charAt(i) == 'G')
         {
            seqReverseCompliment = "C" + seqReverseCompliment;
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.println("incorrect input");
         }
      }
       if ( seqSecond.equals(seqReverseCompliment) )
       {
          System.out.println("These are reverse compliments");
       }
       else if (
       {
          System.out.println("These are not reverse compliments");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the extra variable (seqReverseCompliment). That is what i wanted to do, but my brain wasn't figuring it out.    Like i would need to compare the first char of seqFirst with the last char of seqSecond, but I for some reason don't know how to code that. I think it would be much cleaner